# Adding Version control repository to MonoDevelop

Tags: version-control, monodevelop

Can someone guide me to how to set up version control repositories in MonoDevelop? Using Xcode I have set up a local repository (on my Mac) but I want to use a remote one either on another machine (or on the web). I have looked at the screencast [for using source control](http://monodevelop.com/Documentation/Version_Control_Screencast) but it doesn't explain how to use the 'connect to repository' window. I have set up a repository on a Windows machine (using the Windows Git gui) but MonoDevelop cannot find the path when I try to connect to it (I can read & write other files to the same path with Finder on the Mac).
Also, there seems to be a bug in MonoDevelop in that after failing to connect to the repository, it isn't possible to start the process over again, the only option is to 'remove' from source control which also deletes all the original source files!

(I have experience with Microsoft SourceSafe but not with git). Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have discovered what to enter in the URL for setting up a repository on remote machine:
I didn't know about the "/Volumes..." requirement e.g. /Volumes/macshare - i'm still learning differences from Windows I guess.
As to the bug when removing from source control, this has been notified to MonoDevelop (bug 6014)